# laravel - show name instead of id in a url using routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes

need to show the `project name` instead of the `id` using the route.
I did it but what if I need the `id` in the controller too, as I using it to get the related `project images` and other stuff. how this can be done.

here is my Route

```
Route::model('project/{name}/{sub}', array('uses' => 'projectController@show'));
```

and here is my controller

```
public function show($name)
    {
        $seg = Request::segment(3);

        $pro = Projects::where('pro_title', $name)->first();
        $proImg = ProjectsImages::where('image_id', $id)->get();
        $proPln = ProjectsPlans::where('image_id', $id)->get();
        $services = $pro->pro_serves;
        $service = explode(',', $services);

        switch ($seg) {
            case "project-plans":
                return View::make('projects.projectDetails.verticalPlans', compact('pro', 'proPln'));
                break;
            case "project-images":
                return View::make('projects.projectDetails.projectImages', compact('pro', 'proImg'));
                break;
            case "project-map":
                return View::make('projects.projectDetails.projectPlace', compact('pro'));
                break;
            case "project-features":
                return View::make('projects.projectDetails.projectFeatures', compact('pro', 'service'));
                break;
            default :
                return View::make('projects.projectDetails.aboutProject', compact('pro'));
                break;
        }
    }
```

now as you can see I am successfully got the route named by the project_title but I need the `id` too to get other stuff

can anybody help me how should I accomplish this.

Comment: Cant you get the id by using `$pro->id` ?

Comment: it was all my mistake in my `route` I used `model` instead of `get` solved and working fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can retrieve id in controller

you get all data of projects using

```
$pro = Projects::where('pro_title', $name)->first();
```

then you pass that retrieved id  like

```
 $proImg = ProjectsImages::where('image_id',  $pro->id)->get();
        $proPln = ProjectsPlans::where('image_id', $pro->id)->get();
```

Comment: thanks but now when I try to visit the project images the route will be something like `http://localhost/elarabiaLaravel/project/proName/project-map` I get `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException` any idea

Comment: @YousefAltaf.try to print each step.check wheather data is there ind db

Comment: my `route` uses `/{sub}` as the third pram which will hold the `project-images, plans, etc.` and I switch between them by the `$seg = Request::segment(3);` what should I print sorry didn't get you?

Comment: print one by one like $seg ,$pro etc.so you can get to know whats going wrong

Comment: printed `$pro` got the project information printed `$proImg` got the project images, I think it's something should be done in the route it self check this full error details `$others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);
 
  if (count($others) > 0)
  {
   return $this->getOtherMethodsRoute($request, $others);
  }
 
  throw new NotFoundHttpException;`

Comment: what about $seg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125586/discussion-between-yousef-altaf-and-vision).

Comment: it's `null` because the third pram is missing as I can't even put it in the url if I do it will come back with the error `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException`